# Add and commit files in a tree to SVN

Tags: svn

I have a directory tree under SVN control, and I want to add and commit several new files in the tree.  Some of the files are already under SVN, and others are not.  Sometimes not even the parent directories of the new files are under SVN yet.  I have the names of all the new files, but I do not know which ones are under SVN yet and which ones are not.

I'm looking for a simple way to add and commit all these files.

Adding the files which are not under SVN yet is actually easy: I do `svn add --parents --quiet FILES...`.  This will add all those files which are not under SVN and do nothing for those which are already registered.  But there doesn't seem to be a similar operation for `svn commit`.  When I do `svn commit` on a file that has just been added, it complains that the parent directory is not yet under SVN control.  There does not seem to be a `--parents` option for `svn commit`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, svn commit is recursive by default. Commit from the root directory of the tree, and everything should be committed at once.

Comment: The problem is that there might be some files in the tree that I do not want to commit just yet.  However, I can probably find a subtree that I can commit completely, top-down. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: is it possible via TurtoiseSVN to always add before committing? I keep forgetting adding the files before doing a commit.

Answer (score -1):

```
svn add --force
svn commit -m "yes the damn thing works"
```